# Powershell script to fetch Azure WebApp details

Tags: azure-web-app-service, azure-powershell, azure-app-service-plans

I'm trying to write powershell script which gets all webapps and few properties of each azure web app. Below is the script i tried but it's giving me `Http20Enabled` is not valid property error. I think somehow i'm using the wrong scope.

I need to get properties of `Webapp` and `SiteConfig` of that webapp in a single row in CSV file.

```
Get-AzureRmWebApp | ForEach-Object {
  ($webapp = $_) | Get-AzureRmWebApp -ResourceGroupName {$webapp.ResourceGroup} -Name {$webapp.Name} | select -ExpandProperty SiteConfig | Select-Object @{ 

    Http20Enabled = $_.Http20Enabled
    MinTlsVersion = $_.MinTlsVersion
    AlwaysOn = $_.AlwaysOn
    Cors = $_.Cors
    Owner = {$webapp.Tags.Owner}
    Name = {$webapp.Name}
    ResourceGroup = {$webapp.ResourceGroup}
    HttpsOnly = {$webapp.HttpsOnly}
    ClientAffinityEnabled = {$webapp.ClientAffinityEnabled}
  } 
}| Export-Csv "C:apps1\test.csv"
```

**Updated:**

Tried this :

```
Get-AzureRMWebApp | ForEach-Object {
    $webapp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Name $_.Name 

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -property @{
      Http20Enabled = $webapp.siteconfig.Http20Enabled
      MinTlsVersion = $webapp.siteconfig.MinTlsVersion
      AlwaysOn = $webapp.siteconfig.AlwaysOn
      Cors = $webapp.siteconfig.Cors
      Owner = $webapp.Tags.Owner
      Name = $webapp.Name
      ResourceGroup = $webapp.ResourceGroup
      HttpsOnly = $webapp.HttpsOnly
      ClientAffinityEnabled = $webapp.ClientAffinityEnabled
    } 
}
```

Got the error -

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required
>   by parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. Specified  method is not supported.

PSVersion   5.1.17763.771
AzureRM     5.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you mean to do was assign $webapp to the output of the Get-AzureRMWebApp command.  I am also not really sure how the Select-Object command is supposed to work at the end, but I am assuming you want to have an object to use later.  So you can use the New-Object cmdlet and then pass in the values from the $webapp object as properties.  You don't need to expand the siteconfig property, you can reference the properties directly with dot notation.  This ran on my system and gave me the output below the snippet.

```
Get-AzureRMWebApp | ForEach-Object {
    $webapp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Name $_.Name 

    New-Object -TypeName psobject -property @{
      Http20Enabled = $webapp.siteconfig.Http20Enabled
      MinTlsVersion = $webapp.siteconfig.MinTlsVersion
      AlwaysOn = $webapp.siteconfig.AlwaysOn
      Cors = $webapp.siteconfig.Cors
      Owner = $webapp.Tags.Owner
      Name = $webapp.Name
      ResourceGroup = $webapp.ResourceGroup
      HttpsOnly = $webapp.HttpsOnly
      ClientAffinityEnabled = $webapp.ClientAffinityEnabled
    } 
}


MinTlsVersion         : 1.0
HttpsOnly             : False
Http20Enabled         : False
AlwaysOn              : False
Owner                 :
Name                  : WEBAPP-NAME2
ResourceGroup         : RG-NAME1
Cors                  :
ClientAffinityEnabled : True

MinTlsVersion         : 1.0
HttpsOnly             : False
Http20Enabled         : False
AlwaysOn              : False
Owner                 :
Name                  : WEBAPP-NAME2
ResourceGroup         : RG-NAME1
Cors                  :
ClientAffinityEnabled : True
```

**Answer to second question**

I copied and pasted straight from your question and it worked just fine.  Your AzureRM module could use some updating.

```
PS C:\> $Results = Get-AzureRMWebApp | ForEach-Object {
>>     $webapp = Get-AzureRMWebApp -ResourceGroupName $_.ResourceGroup -Name $_.Name
>>
>>     New-Object -TypeName psobject -property @{
>>       Http20Enabled = $webapp.siteconfig.Http20Enabled
>>       MinTlsVersion = $webapp.siteconfig.MinTlsVersion
>>       AlwaysOn = $webapp.siteconfig.AlwaysOn
>>       Cors = $webapp.siteconfig.Cors
>>       Owner = $webapp.Tags.Owner
>>       Name = $webapp.Name
>>       ResourceGroup = $webapp.ResourceGroup
>>       HttpsOnly = $webapp.HttpsOnly
>>       ClientAffinityEnabled = $webapp.ClientAffinityEnabled
>>     }
>> }
PS C:\> $Results.count
15

PS C:\> Get-Module AzureRM

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Script     6.13.1     AzureRM
```

Comment: Thanks. Does the export to csv works well in your script?

Comment: @Venky - Sorry I missed something when I copied and pasted the first time.  That first line in the loop need to reference $_ or no parameters at all.  I've corrected it in my answer.  Yes, you can add `| Export-Csv -Path <path> -NoTypeInformation` to the end like you had it and it works fine. If this works for you please upvote and mark as the answer! :)

Comment: It's giving this error `The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that 
take pipeline input` on 2nd `Get-AzureRmWebapp`.  I am not using `Az` cmdlets yet.

Comment: @Venky - sorry, I don't have the AzureRM cmdlets anymore.  I updated the answer to use a non-pipeline method.

Comment: getting this error now `Get-AzureRmWebApp : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'ResourceGroupName'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an argument that is 
not null or empty, and then try the command again.`

Comment: Can you edit your question with an “update” under the original and add the code you are using? I’ll find a system with AzureRM to test with.

Comment: Also, what version of AzureRM are you using?

Comment: @Venky I added to my answer.